# The blockchain lookup speed in a local machine

Tags: blockchain, json-rpc, development, block

How to determine the exact required time (seconds, milliseconds) to find a particular block when searching within a local blockchain using address?

Is there any way to make a benchmark to study the lookup speed of the different blockchain research engines?